# Why are spans in Linear Algebra represented using free variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have been doing some refresher work in Khan Academy for Linear Algebra and there was mention of how a column space or any other space can be represented as a fucntion of the free variables and not the other way around.

I am curious about why that would be the case? And would it be the only solution?

I can see it might be a little easier to do it this way since linear models come in a format better suited to such a representation. But would it be wrong to represent it the other way?

Is there really an inherent correctness in such a representation?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "and not the other way around"

Comment: In this video [from KA](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/null-column-space/v/dimension-of-the-null-space-or-nullity?modal=1) we find the pivot vectors of a matrix and its associated variables/constants X are put in an equation. X1 is associated with the pivot vector, except X1 is taken as a function of the other variables. Not the other way around. Which is something that I am still confused by

Comment: Ok. In other words, the **pivot variable** is taken as a function of the other (free) variables and not the other way around.

Comment: You might find [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3714151/81360) to be helpful

Comment: I took a second to read through your answer and I think it makes sense to me now.

Since the pivots are expected to be independent(if I can use a colloqial term, foundational) with defining a space, then we want to have a basis be built around our pivot variables so that all the other points in space are just a reconstitution of these pivot variables.

So we we do pivot variable=equation of other variables...
What we are actually doing is representing our spanning vectors as just the equation that represents the pivot vecors

Comment: So we find our pivots, express them in neat equations. Represent that neatly. Then instead of thinking of free vectors, we just think of a random set of constants to scale/reconstitute these vectors.