# Gaussian Elimination - Free Variable

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

If I had a matrix like so:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&2&8\\0&1&1&1&4\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Would I be able to let the first column be a free variable? if so, how would I solve for any of the other variables?

Comment: Please define "free variable". Are you solving a linear system $A x = b$ for $x$ and the matrix you gave use is $A$?

Comment: How many and which variables do you have? What is the right hand side?

Comment: @Isabelle You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3714172/81360) to be helpful

Comment: @Isabelle Ultimately, the answer is that you can "set $x_1$ as a free variable" because the first column can be written as a linear combination of the others: for instance,
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} = - \frac 12 \pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 0} + \frac 12 \pmatrix{3\\1\\0}.
$$
Whichever columns you select as "free" must be expressible as a linear combination of the "pivot" columns.

Comment: I have 5 columns, so the last column is a constant. It is a system of equations represented in a matrix. I'm wanting to know if I can make the 1 in the first column a free variable